# Theorem 2.1 in Stein Shakarchi , p37, unnecessary path?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

In Stein's Text, he provided the following proof to show the existence of a primitive on an open disc domain,

[image]

---

I am confused, why can we not take the straight line $\gamma'_z$ path connecting $0$ and $z$ and define,
$$ F(z) = \int_{\gamma'_z} f(w) \, dw $$

The argument then proceeds similarly by applying Goursat's Theorem and continuity. Is there anything wrong with this method?

Comment: By the time I dig my copy out and convince myself one way or the other, someone will have answered, I'm sure. Rats.

Comment: Goursat says the integral is $0$ over any triangle?

Comment: @zhw, yes if $f$ is holomorphic on an open set containing the triangle and its interior.

Comment: You are correct then, and as I recall that's the way Rudin does it in RCA